# EASY How do I use the count() and capitalize() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am new to Python and stack overflow. How do I use the count and capitalize functions for my strings? The app I am learning from appears to have this mixed up because it dosen't work in vscode.

It seems like the capitalize function call is ignored. What am I doing wrong? If someone could tell me how to use the *count* function as well I have the same problem. The app I learn from is called Programminz.

This is Python 3

```
practice = "CaPITalIzE mE proPerLy"
practice.capitalize()
print(practice)
```

Comment: Just do `practice = practice.capitalize()`, strings are inmutable, so `.capitalize()` returns a new string.

Answer (score 1):

**string_name.capitalize()**

string_name: It is the name of string of
             whose first character we want
             to capitalize.

Try to use :

string = "CaPITalIzE mE proPerLy"

capitalized_string = string.capitalize()

print('Old String: ', string)
print('Capitalized String:', capitalized_string)